# getElementById returns null even with used window.onload for asynchronously loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, iframe

I've got a problem applying some styles to leaderboard (banner on top) on [this page](http://www.aktualne.cz/?PREVIEWHINT=FCID:38503), which is loaded asynchronously. I've tried to use window.onload, but it still returns me null, when I'm using getElementById. And I don't have access to page in means, I can't move the script to the bottom (before the end body tag).

This is the leaderboard, which is loaded as iFrame:

```
<div class="adWrapperFlightId" id="sas_18258_38503">
<iframe src="http://content.aimatch.com/cent/3/Hornmann_Aktualne_branding_leaderboard.swf.html?click=http://a.centrum.cz/cent/adclick/FCID=38503/fcid=38503/relocate=&clickTAG=http://a.centrum.cz/cent/adclick/FCID=38503/fcid=38503/relocate=" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" noresize="true" frameborder="0" align="left" style="border: 0px none; padding: 0px ;margin: 0px; float:none;" width="1180" height="210"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is the script, I want to apply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="scriptborder">

(function(window, document, undefined){

var border = 'yup';

window.onload = init;

function init(){
if (""!==border) {
var e="1180";
var r = "210";
var t=parent.document.getElementById("sas_18258_38503").parentElement;
t.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<div id="iframeborder"></div>');
borderYes=parent.document.getElementById("iframeborder");
borderYes.style.cssText="border: 1px solid silver; padding: 0px ;margin: 0px; float:none;width:"+(e-2)+"px;height:"+(r-2)+"px;background-image:url('http://i0.cz/reklama/bo/transparent.png');position: absolute;cursor: pointer;";
borderYes.setAttribute("onclick","window.open('http://a.centrum.cz/cent/adclick/FCID=38503/fcid=38503/relocate=', '_blank');");
    }
  }

})(window, document, undefined);

</script>
```

I know this question is possibly duplicate one, but I haven't found anything applied to asynchronously loaded iframe,...or maybe I'm novice in Javascript, which is also true.

Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: What is `parent` in this context?

Comment: The only problem I see with your code is the fact that <div class="adWrapperFlightId" id="sas_18258_38503">...</div> isn't loaded when init is executed.  You need to place your logic into the callback of whatever script is putting that div on the page.

Comment: @tpdietz - O.K., I will try it...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in raw JavaScript but this is i get it working using jquery

$("#myIframeId").load(function(){
       callback(
       //   Here is your call back code

```
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1) Was borderYes properly initiated? From the looks of your code, borderYes is supposed to be an element object? I don't see "var borderYes = document.getElementById('elemID')" or anything like that in the code you posted. Perhaps you instantiated borderYes somewhere else in your code.

2) I've never seen or heard of an object hierarchy of parent.document.getElementById('elemID'). I would expect it to just be document.getElementById('elemID'), omitting "parent."

"parent" is a property that every element has, containing an object reference to the 'parent' object the element is contained in.